# Determine touch start event of javascript in monkey talk tool

Tags: javascript, ios, monkeytalk

I am using monkey talk tool for testing an HTML in my ipad, here i have an HTML image imageA on which i have wrote the touch event (Touch start) in javascript in which i am calling a method which changes the image of imageA.

when i touch it, imageA changes its image while using the monkey talk tool i am not able to simulate this behaviour through mt (Monkey talk) scripts

When i change the touch event to onclick and then run the mt script then it seems to be working fine but i would like to have the functionality on the touch start event.

Is it that their is a work around to detect touches of javascript in monkey talk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,you can do it using `tap()` or `touchDown()` in javascript.
This will help you: [JavaScript API Reference](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-language-reference/scripting-javascript/javascript-api-reference)

Comment: I tried that but its not working, FYI the imageA is an HTML image <img>

Comment: You can see that component using component tree and then use it's monkeyid to find that component.

Comment: Also tried that before posting the question, i am using the correct monkey id but it seems that the touch events are not being identified.Any more suggestions on this?